# Angular use service populated by APP_INITIALIZER in module's @NgModule decorator

Tags: angular, configuration-files, environment, angular7

I need to make an Angular application environment independent, thus I've implemented a function in `app.module.ts` which fetches a config file from the file system:

```
export function load(http: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService): () => Promise<boolean> {
  return (): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise<boolean>(
      (resolve: (a: boolean) => void): void => {
        http
          .get('./assets/config.json')
          .pipe(
            map((config: ConfigModel) => {
              configService.config = config;
              resolve(true);
            }),
            catchError(
              (x: { status: number }, caught: Observable<void>): ObservableInput<{}> => {
                if (x.status !== 404) {
                  resolve(false);
                }
                console.log('Config file could not be loaded, thus using default configuration.');
                configService.config = configService.defaultConfig;
                resolve(true);
                return of({});
              }
            )
          )
          .subscribe();
      }
    );
  };
}
```

In the providers section of the `app.module.ts` I declare a provider to make the application load the config prior application start:

```
providers: [
  ConfigService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: load,
    multi: true,
    deps: [HttpClient, ConfigService]
  }
]
```

Using the dynamically populated config in components works well just by injecting `ConfigService` and calling `.config` on them.

I'm now facing a problem where I need to provide the config to a module's `forRoot()` method in the import statements of the `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
  NgMsAdalModule.forRoot(## I need configService.config.adalConfig here! ##)
]
```

How to make the `ConfigService` available in the module's `NgModule` decorator?

Comment: Have you considered using Angular Universal to inject environment settings? We do this via our Docker / Bamboo build process with great success.

Comment: @Brandon do you have any resources going further into the topic of injecting environment settings with Angular Universal?

Comment: None other than my own experience. I should write a blog post. I'll share any knowledge I have with you in the meantime.